# How to delete duplicate rows from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have duplicate rows in several SQL Server tables but the IDs are different. Is there a query I can run to delete these rows?

Comment: Firstly, how can you tell they're duplicates?

Comment: Secondly, look at this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

Comment: Post some example data for us to see. This may help.

Comment: give us more info! columns, how to see duplicates, etc

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that `ID` has the `IDENTITY` property, is the `PRIMARY KEY` and the table has no other unique constraint/index. Once you have cleansed the data ("treated the symptoms") you should fix the problem ("cure the disease").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full example:

```
create table #test (
id int,
value int
)

insert into #test values (1,2), (2,2), (3,1), (4,2)


delete #test
where id not in ( select min(id) from #test group by value)

drop table #test
```

It will delete all `ids` that have the same `value`, except the `min(id)`.

You just need to alter the `group by` columns to consider all that are needed to be a duplicate row.

Answer (score 2):

Because your answer is not specific I can give you a general answer.

You can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function from SQL Server. Example:

```
WITH CTE (COl1,Col2, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
SELECT COl1,Col2,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COl1,Col2 ORDER BY Col1) AS DuplicateCount
FROM DuplicateRcordTable
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
GO
```

Check this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/) out for more info.